# Flowtype - generic array

Tags: flowtype

How i can write generic function, which take Array of Objects (any type of Object, possible even null and undefined), and filter it to return just valid items of array? If i write it lite this, i will lose genericity :/

```
// @flow

// Types
type Person = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
};

type Car = {
  id: string,
  color: string,
};

// Function definition
const isNotUndefinedOrNull = item => !(item === null || item === undefined);

export const trimList = (list: Array<any> | $ReadOnlyArray<any>): Array<any> => {
  return list.filter(isNotUndefinedOrNull);
};

// Constants
const persons = [{ id: 'p1', name: 'Johny' }, null, undefined];
const cars = [{ id: 'c1', color: 'red' }, null, undefined];

// Calls
const trimmedPersons = trimList(persons);
const trimmedCars = trimList(cars);
```

PROBLEM is, there i have trimmed cars and persons, but flow doesnt know, there is Cars in the trimmedCars list and neither know there is Persons in trimmedPersons list. Flow see just Array and i dont know, how to write is right, to not lose this info.
[Flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQJQEsC2AHWAnALqAFSgCGAzqAEqiQ6zqgDkOJ6AJiYwNyLJgAqAT0wBTMojzCRoAAoicZWADtQAXlABvRKDRsAXKDJ4cqJQHMANNtBLWIg0ZPmrAXx4SpoAMIkcazdao+obGppbWAMawcDgOoc6IbrwoAGIArkoReKjKoGwikKao2cqIUUpGaGQAcrB4AKpK+YVKImwA8jjVadDQ-sUiDKoAfKAAhAAUA0Oq6ko9fQA+i2h4g2qzoBnNpm0AlO4iAB7Y+KDllaHoADKoleoT0Hd4BgCCOCyCADwkSoKjKwAJJQRCQOkpoIJ3p8fn9hns3h8SN9fv81KMtDocCI8GkcConkYAHSFaBrHBTGp1Ro7VodLoLA6JdwoLzKIy-PDiC4EUQKdn+ADaGl0BkYmAAjIwLDY7GKAFKwAAWf0YoBcMvmvRl2wKuzYAF0eDzzr4KOphaKmBEpTKojExdi2GqNTYFjqmnq6UbkmAfL1ueyCFd0G05PyKv4rrcjBM+YoKkyTSG2j4FFGTDdnhMImamchCMRtMQZJR2gAha4AUQAslUZXglfJpKhQEqSAA3aQptim9O-Xvx9kygBGaQIMAQeVgYiUBAA1koEDLi6BG82qt4zWgVOu15nQ2w0xRCQQBzYRMUm35F1P19jN+GExRTKue0+BaeiaAUnB4IYRGkAArNJKmhZFYTRc9WzYZQFyXeAZSVO9YFAeATDWVc7lAEwzCVPAG1QpcCDgMhuyVbDTEgWAiWLYAgA)

Comment: `Array<?Object>` is ok for you, why you don't like it?

Comment: Cuz when i put there Array<?Person>, it return Array<Object>. So i lose information, there are Persons in the array.

Comment: @FrantišekBelšán How about this:
https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1ABSwE4DOsAdqALygCCBBAhmgDwDeAPqKfQLZYBcoIigIBLUgHMANKGj0hAoaImg2AXwB8AbkSQArqQDGKEWVCRYsJgBUBAfnzEy6gBT0BVgJTvQLUASwougTk9JqgqsggoFZYQogGZEKg2I6kRJSgANq+XLwCAOQAsvQEANaw+dKy8qD5AMr0AG4iBvnh0jk8-LX4KCWVMnIoBb0EsM2t4QC62glpKMmEJGkAotwY6BmZM-GJCynLRCsAHihYpAAmW515PYT0A9XDd6Kt0vTi3QCMAEzT2joLM4DokPKAogB1WBlIiA2DApaJNYbNBgyHQ0qw8zw0i6aDQNFgKEwuEI1JHU7nC6E0AAOVgC3gGIAdIggA

Comment: @MarkoSavic Thanks for answer, but i need something diffrent. Look on question, i added "Flow try" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it :)

```
export function trimList<V>(list: Array<?V> | $ReadOnlyArray<?V>): Array<V> {
  return R.filter(isNotUndefinedOrNull, list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As flow has a bug with [Refine array types using filter](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1414) we use explicit type casting `((res): any): T[])`.

```
function filterNullable<T>(items: (?T)[]): T[] {
    const res = items.filter(item => !(item === null || item === undefined);
    return ((res): any): T[]);
}

// Example
const a: number[] = filterNullable([1, 2, null, undefined]);
```

Comment: i make question description better, cuz i think we are not at same page. Do you get me now?